# Append button to bottom of a input group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is there a way in bootstrap to append button to bottom of the input/textarea
instead of appending to the right/left side?

Here is what I've tried:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="Type your notes here..." required></textarea>
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: inline is your friend here :) parent an inline, the button a block :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like bootstrap has no such feature (or at least not well-documented to find it).
So adding 2 simple classes for solving border roundings worked well.

```css
.rounded-bottom-0 {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
}

.rounded-top-0 {
  border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <textarea class="form-control rounded-bottom-0"
            rows="10"
            placeholder="Type your notes here..."
            required></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-top-0">Copy to clipboard</button>
<div>
```

**Notes:**

1. Removing `!important`-s from css would work for Chrome but not for Firefox.
2. Bootstrap's [border-rounding](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/borders/#border-radius) classes didn't work there as well since the borders are already rounded and bootstrap doesn't have class for resetting round from sides.

Answer (score 0):

Use `w-100`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="input-group">
  <textarea class="form-control w-100" rows="10" placeholder="Type your notes here..." required></textarea>
  <div class="input-group-append w-100">
    <button class="btn btn-primary w-100">Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I've noticed a small problem with this solution. Rounding of buttons are broken (remain the same as it would be in case of appending from right)